# How to increase value of an integer higher than 1 in one command?

Tags: c#

You could write `example++;` multiple times in your loop if you need to increase by more than 1, but what if i need to increase by like 100? Is there a way to make it multiply or increase by more than 1? (other than multiplying it in Console.WriteLine)

Comment: do you mean `example = example + 100;`

Comment: Would `example += 100;` do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the comment from peter:

```
example += 100;
```

Means the same as

```
example = example + 100;
```

This is called Compound Assignment and there are [many operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#compound-assignment) that do their work in this way, such as

```
example -= 100;
example *= 100;
```

For the full list, refer to the MSDN linked above

Any assignment in c# returns the assigned value so it can be used as part of a bigger statement. The `+=` is no different, and this will print "x incremented is 101":

```
int x = 1;
Console.WriteLine("x incremented is " + (x+= 100));
```

The only thing worthy of note is that `++` exists in two forms, either `x++` or `++x` - the first form returns the value of x before it was incremented, the second form returns the value after.

```
int x = 1;
Console.WriteLine("x incremented is " + (x++)); //x is now 2 but the message says it is 1
Console.WriteLine("x incremented is " + (++x)); //x is now 3 and the message says it is 3
```

`+=` only returns the value after increment. There is no form that returns x before you add 100 to it

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to increase value of example by an amount x would be `example=example+x`. This is more legible, however you can use the short form `example+=x`.